# plugin development: storing language specific options

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api, multi-language

I'm currently rewriting a little plugin that shows visitors a small info text. This plugin is German only so far and so I want to add multi language support as I am working on a page that should be in English and German.
The text that is displayed to the visitor can be set in the settings interface of the plugin. The given values are stored in a single option in the database.
In my modified plugin I store the settings in separate options, each for one language. I've added a `$_GET` paramter which is used in the setting registration to create a unique name for a language specific option.

My important (stripped-down) parts of my plugin class:

```
class Privacy_Policies {
    // the language to which the text is translated
    public $translation;
    // the options, stored in the database
    public $options;

    public function __construct() {
        // use the current user locale as a fallback
        $this->translation = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : get_user_locale();
        // if an option already exists, edit it
        // use $this->translation to determine the right language
        $this->options = get_option('privacy_policies_' . $this->translation);
        // call registration when settings page gets loaded
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'register_settings');
        // create the settings page
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_settings_page');
    }

    // settings validation, called as callback to register settings
    public function validate_settings($value) {
        if (isset($value['checkbox']) && 1 == $value['checkbox']) {
            $value[ 'checkbox' ] = 1;
        } else {
            $value[ 'checkbox' ] = 0;
        }
        $value['notice'] = normalize_whitespace($value['notice' ]);
        $value['error_message'] = normalize_whitespace($value['error_message']);
        $value['style'] = normalize_whitespace($value['style']);

        return $value;
    }

    // register a distinct option name for each language
    // the function is called when the settings page gets loaded
    public function register_settings() {
        register_setting(
            'privacy_notice_settings_group', 
            'privacy_notice_settings_' . $this->translation,
            array( $this, 'validate_settings' )
        );
    }

    // create the html for the settings page
    // stripped down to a simple checkbox
    public function get_settings_page() { ?>
        <h2><?php echo $this->get_plugin_data('Name'); ?></h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('privacy_notice_settings_group'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td>
                        <!-- important: 'name' must reflect the option name! -->
                        <input type="checkbox" id="privacy_checkbox" name="privacy_notice_settings_<?php echo $this->translation ?>[checkbox]" value="1"
                        <?php if (isset($this->options['checkbox'])) {
                            checked('1', $this->options['checkbox']);
                        } ?> />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    <?php }

    // add settings page
    // called in the admin_menu hook
    public function add_settings_page() {
        add_options_page(
            'Privacy Policies Settings',
            'Privacy Policies',
            'manage_options',
            'privacy_notice_settings_group',
            array( $this, 'get_settings_page' )
        );
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that, whatever locale is in `$this->locale` the setting will **always** be stored in the database as setting of WP's current locale (`get_user_locale()`). I.e. a setting's name that has been composed of `'privacy_notice_settings_' . $this->translation` gets mysteriously recomposed to `'privacy_notice_settings_' . get_user_locale()`.
I suspect the secret lies somewhere burried in `options.php` which the form is calling. But I seem to be unable to debug this.

Comment: And how do you make the site multilanguage? Do you use any ML plugin?

Comment: I'm using WPGlobus: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpglobus/

Comment: for the third argument for `register_setting` you seem to have a validation callback (not included in your code) ... but that would need to be `array('sanitize_callback' => array($this->validate_settings))` in any case. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/

Comment: @majick - thanks for the tip! I've tried your suggestion but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. `$this->validate_settings` is invalid (only $this->validate_settings()` executes immediately which isn't what I need here). The particular line you've pointed out comes from the original implementation of the plugin. I'm not sure `validate_settings` is ever executed properly (I get no error, however). I'll try again later...

Comment: So, where/how do you actually pass `&lang=en` to satisfy the `isset($_GET['lang'])` ?

Comment: @Anastis - well, the `isset($_GET['lang'])` is a condition on which the setting name is based - if it's there it gets appended to the setting name, otherwise the result of `get_user_locale()` is appended. There's no from field that stores this value and it's not part of the data that's stored in the setting itself, it just gives it a name (in `register_settings`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't yet tried to finally fix my issue but dare to say what's wrong: WP doesn't allow me to use `$_GET` directly. It expects these variables to get sanitized by first whitelisting them through the `query_vars` hook and later calling them through a `WP_query` instance - haven't figured out in detail yet but that seems to make sense to me. Here's a post on the wordpress forum that might explain more: [query-string-url-parameter-in-wp-admin-custom-page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-string-url-parameter-in-wp-admin-custom-page/)

Comment: well it may not be the "wordpress way", but there is actually nothing in wordpress to prevent you using `$_GET` key values directly.